# pgadmin font size all messed up

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

pgadmin font size all messed up one day I wake up! I tried
a. restart unclesoft
b. re-install pgadmin
c.[add 'qt.conf'](https://georgik.rocks/how-to-increase-font-size-in-pgadmin-4-on-windows/)
None of above helped.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

oh... After struggled for hours. CTRL with "-" (Minus) like a crazy man bring it back...
(I tried that very first go didnt work. You have to repeat this like crazy)

Comment: How do you make it larger, I have de opposite problem

Comment: perhaps "CRTL +" ?

Comment: Try CTRL + 0 (zero), which is the usual way apps reset zoom to default.

Comment: "Ctrl +" and "Ctrl 0" worked for me on Windows (11). Think you have to click on the right panel to get it to work, as didn't first time, till I found this and persevered.

Answer (score 2):

This can be tricky as CTRL with "+" or "-" does not work when using the symbols from the keypad.

Using CTRL and "+" or "-" from the keyboard (next to backspace) works without issues (Using pgAdmin version 4.7).

Answer (score 0):

For Mac, "command +/-". Thx

Answer (score 0):

Increase the text size on the screen (pgAddmin4):

- variant 1 : ⌘ %
- variant 2 : Shift ⌘ %
- if both variants do not work,
  then: "pgAddmin4" -> "Reset Layout", then try option 1 or 2

Change the size of texts on the screen: ⌘ -

Tested MacBook Pro, macOS Ventura 13.6